# Google Sheets, get column names if Col1 match Col2 or Col3

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I got a problem and not sure how to solve it.

It's related to Column B in "SR Sheet", in this Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U13dvWPk8-hMybmhE1RKZ66y7RXXGPWt91_BNFWIup4/edit?usp=sharing

(can edit)

I got 2 main sheets "SR" and "FormdataFilter".

SR in the main sheet. FormdataFilter is where the data comes from.

**SR Sheet:**

- Col A: contain the name of an item.
- Col B: contain a list of names
  related to the item, seperated by comma. I have input the names
  manually to show what i'm trying to do.

**FormatdataFilter Sheet:**

Each player can pick two items (#1 and #2)

- Col B: Name
- Col C: Item #1
- Col D: Item #2

**SR Sheet** contain a list of items and the players that picked that item.
A player can pick the same item twice.

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {FormdataFilter!G2:G, 
 IF(FormdataFilter!H2:H="", FormdataFilter!I2:I, FormdataFilter!H2:H&
 IF(FormdataFilter!I2:I="",,", ")&FormdataFilter!I2:I)}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help :)